# Xbox one controller rechargeable battery

Tags: voltage-regulator, battery-charging

I wanna make rechargeable batteries for Xbox one controller.i'm new in this field
So I have some questions

1_The controllers voltage input is 2.4-3.0 volt.
Now is any issues if I use li_ion 14500 battery and a voltage regulator to reduce the voltage to 3 volt?

2_how about 3.3 volt SMD regulator?

3_Can i use a  zener diode to prevent battery voltage drop?

and at the end, if there is any tip that helps me in this project please tell me.

Comment: Rechargeable batteries for Xbox controller are available for $9.99, Insignia - Rechargeable Battery Pack for Xbox One. It is very unlikely that you can do better, given the level of your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a 14500 lithium ion battery (nomial 3.6V) and use a regulator for reducing the voltage to 3.0V. But then the 0.6V voltage drop (times current) is just "burned" in the regulator, which means this is not very efficient. For better efficiency, you could use a switching DC/DC converter which converts the input voltage to a fixed output voltage (say 2.7V) without loosing too much energy. (Using a zener diode does not make sense in your context.)